# Problems with multiple relations in one model

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get the participants count of a few target audiences that are related to a scan, and when i am looking into a specific scan it show's me the participant counts related to the target audience of all scans instead the participant counts related to the target audience of that specific scan.

I have the following models:

- scans
- participants
- targetAudience
- scanParticipants (Makes the relation between the “scan”, “participant” & “targetAudience”, it also has some extra data [pivot table, is what they call it i though])

scan.js model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var scanModel = DS.Model.extend({
    targetAudiences:             DS.hasMany('targetAudiences', {async: true}),
    scanParticipants:            DS.hasMany('scanParticipants', {async: true}),
    participants:                Ember.computed('scanParticipants.@each.participant', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants').then(function (scanParticipants) {
            return scanParticipants.mapBy('participant');
        })
    }),
    participantsCount:           Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants.length');
    }),
    participantsCountFinished:   Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants').filterBy('finished', true).get('length');
    }),
});

export default scanModel;
```

target-audience.js model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var targetAudienceModel = DS.Model.extend({
    scanParticipants:            DS.hasMany('scanParticipants', {async: true}),
    participants:                Ember.computed('scanParticipants.@each.participant', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants').then(function (scanParticipants) {
            return scanParticipants.mapBy('participant');
        })
    }),
    participantsCount:           Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants.length');
    }),
    participantsCountFinished:   Ember.computed('scanParticipants.[]', function () {
        return this.get('scanParticipants').filterBy('finished', true).get('length');
    }),
});

export default targetAudienceModel;
```

scan-participant.js model:

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
var scanParticipantModel = DS.Model.extend({
    finished:       DS.attr('boolean'),
    scan:           DS.belongsTo('scan',           {async: true}),
    participant:    DS.belongsTo('participant',    {async: true}),
    targetAudience: DS.belongsTo('targetAudience', {async: true})
});

export default scanParticipantModel;
```

If i am going to a specific scangroup it shows me a list of scans of that scangroup and that works great example:

url `scangroup/1`:

- scan 1 (Participants count: 14, participants finished: 8)
- scan 2 (Participants count: 14, participants finished: 4)

Now when i am going to a specific scan i want to show the stats of each targetAudience that belongs to the scan i choose example:

url `scangroup/1/scan/2`:

- targetAudience 1 (Participants count: 4, participants finished: 1)
- targetAudience 2 (Participants count: 2, participants finished: 1)
- targetAudience 3 (Participants count: 4, participants finished: 0)
- targetAudience 4 (Participants count: 4, participants finished: 2)

But the stats that i get when i am looking at that specific scan (2) is:

- targetAudience 1 (Participants count: 8, participants finished: 3)
- targetAudience 2 (Participants count: 4, participants finished: 4)
- targetAudience 3 (Participants count: 8, participants finished: 1)
- targetAudience 4 (Participants count: 8, participants finished: 4)

How can i make it possible that when i am looking at scan 2 that it only shows the participants count that are related to that targetAudience of scan 2?

I just can't figure it out, im already 3 days trying everything but it seems like its impossible.

I am using:

- Ember 2.1.0
- Ember data 2.1.0

Thanks in advance!

Kindly regards,

Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem!!

I am pushing each targetAudience in a component `scan-stats-target`,
In the component i made computed property `participantsCount`:

```
participantsCount: Ember.computed('targetAudience', function () {
    let scanId           = this.get('scan.id');
    let scanParticipants = this.get('targetAudience.scanParticipants');

    return scanParticipants.filterBy('scan.id', scanId).get('length');
})
```

so easy, i think i worked to long it i couldn't think simple anymore =x!

Someone doesnt understand it just question me and il try to answer it!